# Auto startup false not working for DefaultMessageListenerContainer

Tags: java, jms, spring-integration, ibm-mq

Am using spring integration to listen from ibm mq, i want to deploy my application in dormant mode and start it at the required time. So for that i used auto startup false of DefaultMessageListenerContainer. But still as soon as i start my application it starts reading from the queue.
Queue already exist and some other application is already reading from that queue. i dont want my application to start reading as soon as it id deployed.

```
@Bean()
public DefaultMessageListenerContainer pagn2utcContainer() {
    DefaultMessageListenerContainer container = new DefaultMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(mqConnectionFactory);
    container.setMessageListener(sita2pagnRcvQueueListener());
    container.setDestinationName(jetstarFromArinc);
    container.setAutoStartup(false);
    return container;
}

@Bean()
public ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener sita2pagnRcvQueueListener() {
    ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener listener = new ChannelPublishingJmsMessageListener();
    listener.setRequestChannelName("arinc2pagnRcvChannel");
    return listener;
}

@Bean
public JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint sita2pagnInbound() {
    return new JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint(pagn2utcContainer(), sita2pagnRcvQueueListener());
}

@Bean
public MQQueueConnectionFactory wmqQueueConnectionFactory() throws JMSException {
    MQQueueConnectionFactory mqQueueConnectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    mqQueueConnectionFactory.setHostName(host);
    mqQueueConnectionFactory.setChannel(channel);
    mqQueueConnectionFactory.setPort(Integer.parseInt(port));
    mqQueueConnectionFactory.setQueueManager(queueManager);
    mqQueueConnectionFactory.setTransportType(1);
    return mqQueueConnectionFactory;
}

@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "arinc2pagnRcvChannel", outputChannel = "nullChannel")
public Message<String> arinc2pagnRcv(Message<String> message) {
    return message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The container's lifecycle is managed by the endpoint. You need to set `autoStartup` to `false` on the `JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint` as well.

Comment: Thanks Gary, but am not able to start the listener. Used below code to start it. public void start() {
  sita2pagnInbound().start();
  pagn2utcContainer().start();
 }

Comment: You don't need to start the container; starting the endpoint will start the container. See [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/5073da8a1b5275be5fce639e4d42d037a72f7bf3/spring-integration-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/jms/JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint.java#L192-L201).

Comment: It's still not starting even with just sita2pagnInbound().start(); i don't see any consumer for the Queue.

Comment: Makes no sense. Try DEBUG logging and/or a debugger.

Comment: Hi Gary, with dubug mode it shows that Endpoint is started but still there is no consumer {
  "message" : "tcp://localhost/127.0.0.1:61616@57658 after negotiation: OpenWireFormat{version=12, cacheEnabled=true, stackTraceEnabled=true, tightEncodingEnabled=true, sizePrefixDisabled=false, maxFrameSize=104857600}"
}
{
  "message" : "Established shared JMS Connection"
}
{
  "message" : "started org.springframework.integration.jms.JmsMessageDrivenEndpoint@5a88594a"
}

Comment: Figured it out. Was using @Service annotation, had to use atConfiguration instead